# Netlogo-Why does storing data from turtles into the global variable matrix crash

Tags: netlogo

My program has an array for each turtle, and when I want to store the data in this array to the global variable matrix, the program does not work properly
I want to be able to implement an array for each turtle that stores data into a global variable matrix................................................................................................
The problem arises in：

``
`let n 0 while [n < 40][ let tmp_num1 (array:item get_k n) matrix:set col_k CatNum n tmp_num`

```
Here is my full code
```

```
`extensions [
  array
  matrix]
globals[
  i
  v
  col_k
]

breed[cats cat]
breed[rats rat]
cats-own [
  CatNum
  data_from_rat
  a_array
  GetRatNum
  get_k
  k ;;
]

rats-own[
  kg
  num
]

to setup
  clear-all
  reset-ticks
  set i 0
  set v 0
  creat-animals
  creat-world
  set col_k matrix:make-constant 40 40 0
  ask cats[
    set k 0
    set a_array array:from-list n-values 20 [0]
    set get_k array:from-list n-values 20 [0]
  ]


end


to go
    ask n-of 20 rats[   ;;
    if i < 20 [
   set num i
   set i i + 1
    ]
  ]
  ask rats[
    update
    creat-ratnum
    fd 3
    rt random 90
  ]

  ask n-of 40 cats[
   if v < 40 [
     set CatNum v
     set v v + 1

    ]

  ]
  ask cats[

    let agsets other turtles-here with [breed = rats]
    if count agsets >= 1
    [
      interaction(one-of agsets)
    ]
    fd 3
    lt random 90
    ;;print_array

  ]
  tick
end

to creat-animals

  create-cats 40[
    set shape "cat"
    set size 2
    set color orange
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  ]
  create-rats 20[
    set shape "mouse side"
    set size 2
    set color pink
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  ]
end
to creat-world
  ask patches[
    set pcolor white
  ]
end
to creat-ratnum

 loop[
    if i >= 20 [stop]
   set num i
  set i i + 1



  ]
end
to update
  set kg random-float 1

end

to interaction[provider]



    set data_from_rat([kg] of provider)
    set GetRatNum ([num] of provider)
    let tmp_num (array:item get_k GetRatNum)  ;;
    ifelse tmp_num >= 1 [
     set tmp_num tmp_num + 1
     array:set get_k GetRatNum tmp_num  ;;
     ;print (word "this is:" tmp_num)
  ][
    set tmp_num tmp_num + 1
    array:set get_k GetRatNum tmp_num
  ]
    array:set a_array GetRatNum data_from_rat   ;;
  ;;
   let n 0
    while [n < 40][
    let tmp_num1 (array:item get_k n)
    matrix:set col_k CatNum n tmp_num
  ]
end`
```

``

Comment: You are not increasing `n` inside your `while` loop, which makes NetLogo start an infinite loop. Of course this problem is not NetLogo-specific but it relates to loops in general. Anyway I suggest you spend some time to take care of your code's tidiness and etiquette, which will be useful both in general and here when you seek help

Comment: I made a low-level mistake, thank you for taking the time to read and point it out, and for your sincere advice, I will try to improve the readability of my code